# Rerun a macro when a combobox value in a userform is changed

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a userform with a combobox to select the training type for various employee classes.

[image]

When the user selects one of the options from the dropdown menu it runs the macro below.

```
Private Sub TrainingType_Selection_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim TrainingType_Selection As String

TrainingType_Selection = Hiring_Validation_Form.TrainingType_Selection.Value

If TrainingType_Selection = "Sustain - 30" Or TrainingType_Selection = "Sustain - 60" Then
    Hiring_Validation_Form.LinkingECPID_Selection.Visible = True
    Hiring_Validation_Form.LinkingECP_Label.Visible = True
End If

If TrainingType_Selection <> "New Hire" Then
    Hiring_Validation_Form.ReqReasonLv1_Selection.Visible = False
    Hiring_Validation_Form.Label6.Visible = False
    Hiring_Validation_Form.ReqReasonLv2_Selection.Visible = False
    Hiring_Validation_Form.Label11.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

The problem I'm running into is that if someone makes a selection from the drop-down menu and then changes their mind and selects another value from the drop-down menu it isn't re-running the macro.  For example they change it from the above "New Hire" to "Sustain - 30".  I have a clear button on the userform, but that clears the entire form which would not be ideal in a situation where the user only wants to change one input, not completely start over.

[image]

How do I get the TrainingType_Selection_Change() macro to re-run again when the combobox selection is changed

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

disables screen updates even after the macro has finished running.

Add

`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

as the last line before `End Sub` to re-enable them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a way to address this issue by using AfterUpdate()
I added the below macro and it now updates the entire form when selections are changed.

```
Private Sub TrainingType_Selection_AfterUpdate()

    TrainingType_Selection = Hiring_Validation_Form.TrainingType_Selection.Value

    Hiring_Validation_Form.LinkingECPID_Selection.Visible = False
    Hiring_Validation_Form.LinkingECP_Label.Visible = False
    Hiring_Validation_Form.ReqReasonLv1_Selection.Visible = True
    Hiring_Validation_Form.Label6.Visible = True
    Hiring_Validation_Form.ReqReasonLv2_Selection.Visible = True
    Hiring_Validation_Form.Label11.Visible = True
    Hiring_Validation_Form.Label21.Visible = True
    Hiring_Validation_Form.NewHireSup_Selection.Visible = True

    Call TrainingType_Selection_Change

End Sub
```